# Upgrade MS Sql Report Server 08 for Dundas charts

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs, ssrs-2008

We have ms sql server 2008, however the new dundas charts are not available on the report server. How do I upgrade the report server so it gets the new dundas charts as well. Dundas charts are a part of Microsoft charts now in the new version of the report server.

Your help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK (99% sure) the Dundas components that Microsoft licensed for SSRS in SQL Server 2008 are present in all versions of SQL Server 2008, thus if you're already running 2008 then there is nothing to upgrade.
Where are you seeing that they are missing?  Which do you think you are missing?  If you see for example the donut chart then they are there.

Comment: Not on my VS 2008 BI, i'm gonna try upgrading and install SQL 2008 BI on the machine. I'm not able to see the charts on my Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about using .NET Framework 3.5 for charting, that is a separate download:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en

http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlrsteamblog/archive/2008/10/25/microsoft-chart-controls-for-net-framework-35.aspx

Comment: No not talking about ms chart. i mean the chart controls on SQL Visual studio BI 2008